# React Native TextInput returnKeyType not working

Tags: react-native

I have a number of TextInput in my `react-native` application and I want that if user clicks on next key, the next input must be focused. I am trying to do this with returnKeyType prop passed to all the TextInput. However this doesn't work as intended ,i.e. next input is not focused. And my code for same looks like

```
<TextInput
              ref={firstInputForDaysInterestTextInputRef}
              value={closingCosts.firstInputForDaysInterest}
              onChangeText={value =>
                onStateChange('firstInputForDaysInterest', value)
              }
              onEndEditing={event =>
                onEndEditing(
                  'firstInputForDaysInterest',
                  event.nativeEvent.text,
                )
              }
              placeholderTextColor={colors.placeholderColor}
              placeholder={constants.common.zeroPlaceholder}
              autoCapitalize="none"
              returnKeyType="next"
              onFocus={() => onFocus(elementName)}
              keyboardType="decimal-pad"
              style={[
                styles.textInput,
                styles.textInputWidth,
                styles.textInputMargin,
              ]}
            />
```

The workaround that I thought was passing ref and then focusing the next input onEndEditing, but if I does this the textinput will not be closed when I tap outside the textInput. So how can I make my text input to focus on next one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use onSubmitEditing prop to focus the next input for example:

```
 const firstInputForDaysInterestTextInputRef = React.useRef()
  const secondInputForDaysInterestTextInputRef = React.useRef()

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
            <TextInput
              ref={firstInputForDaysInterestTextInputRef}
              placeholderTextColor={'gray'}
              placeholder={'first'}
              autoCapitalize="none"
              returnKeyType="next"
              keyboardType="decimal-pad"
              onSubmitEditing={()=>secondInputForDaysInterestTextInputRef.current?.focus()}
              style={[
                styles.textInput,
                styles.textInputWidth,
                styles.textInputMargin,
              ]}
            />
            <TextInput
              ref={secondInputForDaysInterestTextInputRef}

              placeholderTextColor={'gray'}
              placeholder={'second'}
              autoCapitalize="none"
              returnKeyType="next"
              onFocus={() => alert('I am focused !')}
              keyboardType="decimal-pad"
              style={[
                styles.textInput,
                styles.textInputWidth,
                styles.textInputMargin,
              ]}
            />

    </View>
  );
```

Example on [Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@hassan190011/focus-next-input)

Comment: Is this function triggered on the press of next button only?

Comment: it is a callback that is called when the text input's submit button is pressed with the argument {nativeEvent: {text, eventCount, target}}

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the textinput (hide keyboard) when pressing somewhere else in the app, wrap it it like this for example:

```
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
<View style={styles.container}>
<TextInput />
</View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Don't forget to import TouchableWithoutFeedback and Keyboard from 'react-native'

Comment: My TouchableWithoutFeedback does not fire inside my FlatList cells, so I preferred Hassan's answer.